# Efficiency of Rcpp sample v. C++ shuffle

Tags: c++, r, rcpp, shuffle

I'm trying to optimize an algorithm for R. Initially, I wrote the algorithm using Rcpp (and Rcpp vectors, etc.) but subsequently rewrote it using standard C++ vectors and only translating it to Rcpp at the final stage. However, the component of the C++ algorithm that involves `shuffle` seems quite slow. In fact, translating back and forth to an Rcpp vector so that I can use the Rcpp/R `sample` function is much faster. This surprises me.

Here's a minimally reproducible example:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
#include <random>
#include <algorithm>

// [[Rcpp::export]]

List test_cpp(int n, int x)  {

  List return_list(n);

  std::vector<int> v;
  v.reserve(x);

  for(int i = 0; i < x; ++i) {
    v.push_back(i);
  }

  std::random_device rd;
  std::mt19937 g(rd());

  for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i)  {
    std::shuffle(v.begin(), v.end(), g);
    return_list(i) = v;
  }

  return return_list;
}


// [[Rcpp::export]]

List test_r(int n,
            int x)  {

  List return_list(n);

  std::vector<int> v;
  v.reserve(x);

  for(int i = 0; i < x; ++i){
      v.push_back(i);
    }

  IntegerVector vs = wrap(v);

  for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i)  {
    IntegerVector s_v = sample(vs, v.size());
    std::vector<int> s_v_c = as<std::vector<int>>(s_v);
    return_list(i) = s_v_c;
  }

  return return_list;
}
```

The first function using C++ `shuffle` is significantly slower than the version using Rcpp `sample` until you're shuffling a vector of ~50,000 elements. For an example closer to most of my use cases, the following produces median times of ~13 ms for the Rcpp `sample` v. ~20 ms for C++ `shuffle`.

```
n <- 1000
x <- 999

speed <- bench::mark(min_iterations = 100, 
                       check = FALSE,
                       cpp = test_cpp(n, x),
                       rcpp = test_r(n, x)
                       )

  ggplot2::autoplot(speed) +
    ggplot2::theme_minimal() +
    ggplot2::xlab(NULL) +
    ggplot2::ylab(NULL)
```

[image]

It's likely that I've mucked up the C++ code. If so could someone show me my mistake? Or is it that `shuffle` is just slow and I should use a different C++ algorithm? Or is there some penalty in calling an algorithm/random number generator outside of R/Rcpp that explains this difference in performance? Thankful for any suggestions.

**Edit** To illustrate that the inefficiency for the C++ versions doesn't come from having to convert standard vectors to IntegerVectors, I've modified the Rcpp version so that after sampling IntegerVectors are superfluously converted to standard vectors (and then back to IntegerVectors).

**Update**

I've experimented a bit with alternative pseudo random number generators. [This post](https://thompsonsed.co.uk/random-number-generators-for-c-performance-tested) suggest that the Mersenne Twister pseudo random number generator I use above is relatively slow compared to some alternatives. I tried the pseudo random number generators coded [in this post](https://arvid.io/2018/07/02/better-cxx-prng/) and they are indeed faster but they don't massively improve performance. Here are my simplified test functions.

```
// [[Rcpp::export]]

void test_pcg(int x)  {
  std::vector<int> v;   
  v.reserve(x);
  for(int i = 0; i < x; ++i) {
    v.push_back(i);
  }
  std::random_device rd;   
  pcg g(rd);
  std::shuffle(v.begin(), v.end(), g);
}


  // [[Rcpp::export]]

  void test_mt(int x)  {
    std::vector<int> v;
    v.reserve(x);
    for(int i = 0; i < x; ++i) {
      v.push_back(i);
    }
    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937 g(rd());
    std::shuffle(v.begin(), v.end(), g);
  }


// [[Rcpp::export]]

void test_splitmix(int x)  {
  std::vector<int> v;   
  v.reserve(x);
  for(int i = 0; i < x; ++i) {
    v.push_back(i);
  }
  std::random_device rd;   
  splitmix g(rd);   
  std::shuffle(v.begin(), v.end(), g);
}



// [[Rcpp::export]]

void test_xorshift(int x)  {
  std::vector<int> v;   
  v.reserve(x);
  for(int i = 0; i < x; ++i) {
    v.push_back(i);
  }
  std::random_device rd;   
  xorshift g(rd);
  std::shuffle(v.begin(), v.end(), g);
}


// [[Rcpp::export]]

void test_rcpp(int x)  {
  IntegerVector v = seq(0, x);   
  IntegerVector s_v = sample(v, x);
}
```

For a vector of 1,000, the Rcpp version is still massively faster, ~13 ms compared to 20 ms for the fastest RNG's with C++ shuffle.

From what I understand, C++ shuffle implements the Fisher - Yates (Knuth) shuffle. My conjecture now is that the Rcpp sample function doesn't implement the Fisher-Yates shuffle when all elements are sampled without replacement but instead utilizes a sorting algorithm? Perhaps there's a similar algorithm in C++ that would be faster than shuffle for my application?

Comment: Could this not be explained by the extra time taken to convert 1,000 std vectors into NumericVectors? In the r version you allocate and sample without having to copy anything, but in the c++ version you sample then copy the sample.

Comment: Good guess but no, that doesn't seem to be the problem. See my edit. After converting back and forth for the Rcpp version performance is essentially unchanged.

Comment: Perhaps this is caused by using the Mersenne Twister pseudo random number generator in C++? I understand that it's relatively slow compared to some other approaches?

Comment: FWIW when I run this (Ubuntu 21,10, g++-11) I get an outcome in which the cpp results sits (somewhat rightly) between the two heaps of the Rcpp result. I am more worried about the variability, ie why is Rcpp 'bi-modal' here?   You also 'do a lot' in your functions (the whole vector allocation / preparation) so it's not how I would look at it.  But the main upshot that the _net_ result is rather close between both, while they use _fundamentally different algorithms to sample_ so in a way aren't you just "getting our what you are putting in"?  It's maybe just not that apples-to-apples.

Comment: Have you looked into (my) `dgrng` package? It gives you access to some faster RNGs and the [`sample_int`](https://daqana.github.io/dqrng/articles/cpp-api.html#random-sampling-1) function might be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As alluded to in my comment, your functions may 'do too much'.  Here is simplified example (which is also nonsensical as we likely alter the input vector each time) but it distills your question down to 'is sample faster than shuffle from the standard library'.  And it is not.

[image]

My modified code follows below.

##### Code

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
#include <random>
#include <algorithm>

// [[Rcpp::export]]
Rcpp::IntegerVector shuffle_cpp(Rcpp::IntegerVector x)  {
    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937 g(rd());
    std::shuffle(x.begin(), x.end(), g);
    return x;
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
Rcpp::IntegerVector sample_rcpp(Rcpp::IntegerVector x)  {
    return sample(x, x.size());
}

/*** R
v <- seq(1, 1e6)
res <- bench::mark(min_iterations = 100, check = FALSE, shuffle_cpp(v), sample_rcpp(v))
res
ggplot2::autoplot(res) + ggplot2::theme_minimal() + ggplot2::ylab(NULL)
*/
```

Comment: I ran this and got similar results, but for a sample size of 1,000 (closer to my actual use case), Rcpp is substantially faster (~ on par with my results above).

Comment: Cannot say I reproduce. Here, using `v <- 1:1e4` for a shorter vector leads for me to two near-identical results (medians of 55 microsec vs 70 microsec) with fairly 'vertical' plots (in which `Rcpp` has the wider tiail from usual R `gc()` ops.  People who spend more time on benchmarks sometimes warn against such microbenchmarks with little data.

Comment: Makes sense but as I need to optimize this for small samples (~1,000) I don't see any alternative than to benchmark small samples. I understand though that this means the majority of runtime might be from overhead, etc. I'll accept this answer as it's probably most relevant for the community. In my case, I was able to write a minimal implementation of shuffle that was comparable to Rcpp sample on my machine.